# How to create a PDF file in an UWP app?

Tags: pdf, uwp

Is there any way to create a pdf (from HTML view) on a Windows 10 app? I've tried the solution with the printing API and the pdf-printer. This works but there seems to be no way to do this silent without an UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3rd party libraries you can buy who can do that. With the free libraries like PDFSharp you need libraries that are not available today in UWP. You can create an AppService to handle that (have a look at -github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample)